# How can I remake this array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make the java list so that it goes from the right corner down by 3 positions in descending order, and then moves on to the next column and repeats the same process. Until it reaches 1.

```
int n = 34;
int [][] a = new int [10][10];
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<=3-i; j++){
        if (j >= 0)
            a[i][j] = n--;
    }
}

for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? and what is n = 34 and why 34?

Comment: 34 is the starting value and then it goes down by 3 values, its hard to explain in words

Comment: the a[0][0]=34 then a[1][0]=33 and it goes down to a[3][0] and then goes to next column.

Comment: So you want to fill the first 3 rows of each column, if you start with 34 the last filled cell will be 5 not 1.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the title is poorly explained. But the n=1 is at a[9][9].

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
int n = 34;
int [][] a = new int [10][10];

for(int col = 0; col <= 9; col++) {
    for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        if(n > 0) {
            a[row][col] = n--;
        }
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output would be:

```
34  30  26  22  18  14  10  6   2   0   
33  29  25  21  17  13  9   5   1   0   
32  28  24  20  16  12  8   4   0   0   
31  27  23  19  15  11  7   3   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an image here? Because you kinda get the idea but not really. When the n=1 it needs to be at a[9][9]

Comment: So the values of the first column would be from 34 to 31 and then it goes to the next column and skips the first row. The value in the next column would be from 30 to 27.